# My batch game wont start

Tags: batch-file

So recently I spent a while making this mini text game. every time i try to run it the file just starts at :Fight and not :Start tis is really annoying and once you get there you cant even select a option for fight or run. Please help. And dont judge the game. Thanks

```
@echo off
title: My game!
color 0a
:loop
echo My game!
cls
goto Start
:Start
cls color 3c
echo Hello welcome to my game If this works.....
cls
echo before you start the game make sure that you turned of the hair curler,
echo didnt leave your keys in the car and locked the front door, and THEN you have to make
echo sure that you ARE READY
cls
color 0c
echo WHAT ARE YOU DOING HERE!?!
echo Get out!
color 09
echo A giant monster aproaches you, you dont stop to see what it is chasing you.
color 0c
echo Im gonna demolish you!!
cls
color 09
echo you stop running, the monster is far behind you.You look around and  you are in
echo some kind of dungeon
echo then you start to wonder if you could actually try and fight this thing!
cls
color 09
echo Options
echo 1 try and fight this darn thing!
echo 2 keep running
set /p y=
if %% == 1 goto fight
if %% == 2 goto run

:fight
cls
color 09
echo suddenly you find a pocket nife in your cargo jeans! Very conveniant am i right?
echo so you run up to the monster and slay it!
goto scene two

:run
echo youtire quickly and the monster catches up and swiftly kills you
goto GAME OVER

:GAME OVER
wow nice job you managed to die on the first level
echo Options
echo 1 Try again!
echo 2 Be a wuss and quit
set /p y=
if %% == 1 goto Start
if %% == 2 goto quitter

:quitter
cls
color 09
echo Nice job quitter.

:scene two
color 09
echo wow nice job!
echo so far you have done a nice job!
```

Comment: `if %% == 1` should read `if %y% == 1` (also for `2`)... after these `if` lines you should also handle the case when the user entered anything other than `1` or `2`...

Comment: `choice /c 12` only allows 1 or 2 to be entered. See `Choice /?`. To test `if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo 1 chosen` and `if errorlevel 2 if not errorlevel 3 echo 2 chosen`.

Comment: Thanks for that guys im pretty new to this kind of stuff and when ever I try to run this, I goes straight to :scene two if its a bug in the code or if im opening it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a few things I need to tell you. First of all, if you want people to be able to see what the text is in batch, you need to give the program a reason to stop so people can read it. A the end of the :Start section you have the

```
set /p y=
```

That gives the program a reason to stop because it is waiting for the user to enter some sort of input but you want you can also use.

```
pause <nul
```

Then after the

```
set /p y=
```

You have the

```
if %% == 1 goto fight
if %% == 2 goto run
```

That is almost all fine and dandy except for one thing. You forgot to put the y in between the %%.

It should look like this.

```
if %y% == 1 goto fight
if %y% == 2 goto run
```

Adding the y in between the %'s means you want the file to look at the variable y and see if it is equal to 1 or 2.

This should solve your problem, if not just comment on this.